# Is there any faster way instead of using preg_match in the following code?

Tags: php, xml

this code finds if there is the string 2004 in `<date_iso></date_iso>` and if it is so, I echo some data from that specific element that the search string was found.

I was wondering if this is the best/fastest approach because my main concern is speed and the XML file is huge. Thank you for your ideas.

this is a sample of the XML

```
<entry ID="4406">
    <id>4406</id>
    <title>Book Look Back at 2002</title>
    <link>http://www.sebastian-bergmann.de/blog/archives/33_Book_Look_Back_at_2002.html</link>
    <description></description>
    <content_encoded></content_encoded>
    <dc_date>20.1.2003, 07:11</dc_date>
    <date_iso>2003-01-20T07:11</date_iso>
    <blog_link/>
    <blog_title/>
</entry>
```

this is the code

```
<?php
$books  = simplexml_load_file('planet.xml');
$search = '2004';
foreach ($books->entry as $entry) {
    if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($search) . '/i', $entry->date_iso)) {
        echo $entry->dc_date;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, put up a timer so you know if things get better.

You're repeating `'/' . preg_quote($search) . '/i'`for each book. You should create the search string only once or else you are wasting time:

```
<?php
$books  = simplexml_load_file('planet.xml');
$search = '2004';
$regex = '/' . preg_quote($search) . '/i';
foreach ($books->entry as $entry) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $entry->date_iso)) {
        echo $entry->dc_date;
    }
}
?>
```

If you are only looking for 2004 or similar you might analyze if simpler functions would be faster e.g. `strpos`.

Also the `/i` modifier might be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware, that if you use `strpos` you should use the `!==` operator to check for an occurance of your haystack. If `2004` is at position 0 the `!=` will evaluate true.

```
<?php
$books  = simplexml_load_file('planet.xml');
$search = '2004';
foreach ($books->entry as $entry) {
    if (strpos($entry->date_iso, $search) !== false) {
        echo $entry->dc_date;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not exactly be an answer you're looking for, but I would imagine that the function `simplexml_load_file` is somewhat expensive on a large XML file since it creates a lot of objects containing information about the elements, attributes, values, contents, etc.

For that reason I would try finding matching elements with `preg_match` first (match entire `entry` tags that contain 2004 in their respective `date_iso` tags), then either load just these matches with `simplexml_load_file` to extract the desired information, or (possibly even better) use `preg_match` to do the same thing.

Comment: `simplexml` is *simple*, `preg_match` (in a loop!) is way more expensive.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I would think it would depend on the XML and what exactly you're looking for in it.